# Set font size in certain column for whole google sheet document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 20 different sheets and a lot of columns in each sheet.
I would like to set the font size to 20 in column cj leaving the rest of the columns with their original font size.
This setting should be applied to all sheets in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can literally be accomplished with one line of code:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(sh=>sh.getRange('CJ:CJ').setFontSize(20));
}
```

**References:**

- [setFontSize(fontSize)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setfontsizefontsize)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Thanks @Marios. I thought so but missed out on the forEach() part.